# Can't find fragment by tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using support package v4.

```
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragContainer1, new ModelListFragment(), FRAG_MODEL_LIST);
ft.add(R.id.fragContainer2, new TrimListFragment(), FRAG_TRIM_LIST);
ft.commit();

Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(
            MainActivity.FRAG_MODEL_LIST);
Log.d("MY", "found fragment: " + (fragment != null));
```

Always returns "found fragment: false". I'm missing something really obvious here, what is it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can see in [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29):

> The commit does not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work
>   on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.

that's why you doesn't see your fragment just after commit().

Comment: And if you _really_ want to transaction to be applied, then use [executePendingTransactions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions())

Answer (score 2):

I agree with with [Roosmaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188083/roosmaa),
[`executePendingTransactions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29) after a `commit()` works perfectly fine.